# is it possible to capture browser console logs from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, browser, console.log

My jenkins job starts the application which launches in default browser say, chrome.

is it possible to capture browser console logs from jenkins when application is launched?

This is not for UI/Selenium automation.

Comment: Is this app containerized ?

Comment: yeah.. jenkins runs in kubectl POD

Comment: Did u check pod logs if u could find something related to browser ?

Comment: no, but wondering does the POD store browser logs?

Comment: No this use case is new but i would suggest u to exec into the pod and check  /var/log/jenkins/jenkins. log